# Check installation of SQL Server 2008 Native Client

Tags: sql-server, delphi

How to check using Delphi code, if Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client is installed?

Comment: "find out if Delphi is installed "  Do you actually mean how to find out whether MicroSoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client is installed using code in a Delphi app?

Comment: I cannot understand the question. The text doesn't quite make sense. Could you perhaps reword it to make it more clear?

Comment: MartynA yes, sorry for my language :) Quickly: How to check is installed mssql native client in delphi code.

Comment: Please don't ask the question in comments. Please edit the question.

Comment: ok, i have edit my question :)

Comment: Are you 100% positive that you need the native client installed?  I recently uninstalled mine, then replaced the 64-bit version of Sql Server 2014 by the 32-bit version, and now I don't have a Native Client subkey as per the linked answer posted by @kobik, but my Delphi Sql Server apps still work fine.